# Optional parameter in function php?

Tags: php, function, arguments, option-type

i was having a look at a php script (namesilo module for whmcs) and found this function

```
function namesilo_transactionCall($callType, $call, $params)
```

and later in the script, it is called with the following code

```
namesilo_transactionCall("getNameServers", $apiServerUrl . "/api/getDomainInfo?version=1&type=xml&key=$apiKey&domain=$sld.$tld");
```

When it is called there is only two parameters and when the function was declared, the $params was not made optional. How is it possible. I am relatively new to php

Comment: I think it's not possible! something is wrong

Answer (score 1):

I saw @Alireza Fallah comment, and decided to answer . Why it`s impossible?

```
 <?php 

  function namesilo_transactionCall($callType, $call, $params){
    var_dump($callType);
  }

  namesilo_transactionCall(1,1);
  // OUTPUT
  1

 ?>
```

If you doesnt pass defined not-optional agrument - interpreter generate `Warning` like:

```
Warning: Missing argument 3 for namesilo_transactionCall()
```

Set `error_reporting(0)` - and you never see this. You can ,in general, not specify all parameters like as here:

```
 function A(){  
   print_r(func_get_args());
 }

 // and call 

 A(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8....N);
```

And this code will work. See more about [functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php) in PHP.